# Compare dictionary with another dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying, as the title suggests, to compare a dictionary with another dictionary. It's for comparing bigrams from 1 dictionary with another dictionary.

I'm using a console application to load a file. The application reads this file and adds every 2 letters (for instance; hey becomes he and ey) as a key, and the value will be how often the bigram is seen in percentage (in this case 50% for he and 50% for ey). I got to the part where I'm able to do this.

Now the tricky part is to compare the recently added bigrams with a second file (text). I'm adding the second file to another dictionary. So now I have 2 dictionaries (1 for the first file and the second for the second file).

Now I want to compare those 2 dictionaries and see what bigrams aren't in one or the other (for instance; first directory has he, ey; second directory has he, ey, yg, gu, uy, ys). So yg, gu, uy, ys should come up.

Here's my code:

```
static StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder();
static Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
static Dictionary<string, double> dNL = new Dictionary<string, double>();
static Dictionary<string, double> dDE = new Dictionary<string, double>();
static Dictionary<string, double> dFR = new Dictionary<string, double>();
static Dictionary<string, double> dSP = new Dictionary<string, double>();
static Dictionary<string, double> dEN = new Dictionary<string, double>();
static Dictionary<string, double> dIT = new Dictionary<string, double>();

static List<string> fileList = new List<string>();
static List<string> dConverted = new List<string>();
static List<string> dConvertedNL = new List<string>();
static List<string> dConvertedDE = new List<string>();
static List<string> dConvertedFR = new List<string>();
static List<string> dConvertedSP = new List<string>();
static List<string> dConvertedEN = new List<string>();
static List<string> dConvertedIT = new List<string>();

static string text;
static string languageChosen;
static string gecombineerdeLetters;
static int value = 0;
static int totaleNGram = 0;
static string[] fileRead;
static char[] tekst;

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Start:
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to this program. We need some text to start getting results. Please enter a Language your text is in:");
    Console.WriteLine("press 1 - 7 / enter 'exit' to close the program");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Dutch / 2. German / 3. French / 4. Spanish / 5. English / 6. Italian / 7. Enter unknown language");
    Console.WriteLine();
    languageChosen = Console.ReadLine();
    if (languageChosen == "1" || languageChosen == "2" || languageChosen == "3" || languageChosen == "4" || languageChosen == "5" || languageChosen == "6")
    {
        calculateChanceKnown();
        Console.WriteLine();
        goto Start;
    }
    else if (languageChosen == "7")
    {
        OpenReadFile();
        // compare to every language
        // first convert to list
        dConverted = d.Keys.ToList();
        dConvertedNL = dNL.Keys.ToList();
        dConvertedDE = dDE.Keys.ToList();
        dConvertedFR = dFR.Keys.ToList();
        dConvertedSP = dSP.Keys.ToList();
        dConvertedEN = dEN.Keys.ToList();
        dConvertedIT = dIT.Keys.ToList();
        // compare d against each other list to see which has the most simularities
        //List<string> firstNotSecond = dConverted.Except(dConvertedNL).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine();
        goto Start;
    }
    else if(languageChosen == "exit")
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong input, try again!");
        Console.WriteLine();
        goto Start;
    }

    Console.Read();
}

static void calculateChanceKnown()
{
    OpenReadFile();

    switch (languageChosen)
    {
        case "1":
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in d)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}, Chance = {2}%", kvp.Key, kvp.Value, ((double)kvp.Value / totaleNGram) * 100);
                dNL.Add(kvp.Key, ((double)kvp.Value / totaleNGram) * 100);
                //if key already exists -> add +1 to totaleNGram -> d[gecombineerdeletters] +1 -> calculate % again
            }
            d.Clear();
            //foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> kvp in dNL)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("Bigram = {0}, Chance = {1}%", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            //}
            break;
        case "2":
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in d)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}, Chance = {2}%", kvp.Key, kvp.Value, ((double)kvp.Value / totaleNGram) * 100);
                dDE.Add(kvp.Key, ((double)kvp.Value / totaleNGram) * 100);
            }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> kvp in dDE)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bigram = {0}, Chance = {1}%", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }
            break;
        case "3":
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in d)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}, Chance = {2}%", kvp.Key, kvp.Value, ((double)kvp.Value / totaleNGram) * 100);
                dFR.Add(kvp.Key, ((double)kvp.Value / totaleNGram) * 100);
            }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> kvp in dFR)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bigram = {0}, Chance = {1}%", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }
            break;
        case "4":
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in d)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}, Chance = {2}%", kvp.Key, kvp.Value, ((double)kvp.Value / totaleNGram) * 100);
                dSP.Add(kvp.Key, ((double)kvp.Value / totaleNGram) * 100);
            }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> kvp in dSP)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bigram = {0}, Chance = {1}%", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }
            break;
        case "5":
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in d)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}, Chance = {2}%", kvp.Key, kvp.Value, ((double)kvp.Value / totaleNGram) * 100);
                dEN.Add(kvp.Key, ((double)kvp.Value / totaleNGram) * 100);
            }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> kvp in dEN)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bigram = {0}, Chance = {1}%", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }
            break;
        case "6":
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in d)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}, Chance = {2}%", kvp.Key, kvp.Value, ((double)kvp.Value / totaleNGram) * 100);
                dIT.Add(kvp.Key, ((double)kvp.Value / totaleNGram) * 100);
            }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> kvp in dIT)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bigram = {0}, Chance = {1}%", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

static void OpenReadFile()
{
    var fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog { Multiselect = false, Title = "Open Text File", Filter = "txt files (*txt)|*.txt| word files (*.doc, *.docx)|*.doc; *docx" };
    using (fileDialog)
    {
        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileDialog.FileName);
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                fileList.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }
    fileRead = fileList.ToArray();
    tekst = string.Join(string.Empty, fileRead).ToCharArray();

    foreach (char c in tekst)
    {
        if (!char.IsPunctuation(c)) newText.Append(c);
    }
    text = newText.ToString();
    text.ToLower();
    text = Regex.Replace(text, @"[\s+]", "");
    tekst = text.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < tekst.Count() - 1; i += 1)
    {
        gecombineerdeLetters = string.Format("{0}{1}", tekst[i], tekst[i + 1]);
        //Console.WriteLine(gecombineerdeLetters);

        if (!d.TryGetValue(gecombineerdeLetters, out value))
        {
            d.Add(gecombineerdeLetters, 1);
            totaleNGram += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            d[gecombineerdeLetters] += 1;
            totaleNGram += 1;
        }
    }

}
```

What I've tried:

- Using the except<>
- SequenceEqual

Every time I tried to compare the same file it would give me one bigram that wasn't in either directory.

Comment: `dict1.Keys.Except(dict2.Keys)` and vice versa?

Comment: @itsme86 that's what I thought as well, but for some reason I still get a bigram that isn't in either directory.

Comment: Well that's just impossible!

Comment: @itsme86 Either I'm making a really dumb mistake, but when I do your answer, i get for (file 1 hey guys and file 2 hey) sh returned

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DictionaryComparer
{
    public List<string> CompareDictionaries(IDictionary<string, double> first, IDictionary<string, double> second)
    {
        var dictionary  = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var f in first)
        {
            if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(f.Key))
            {
                dictionary.Add(f.Key, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary[f.Key]++;
            }
        }

        foreach (var f in second)
        {
            if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(f.Key))
            {
                dictionary.Add(f.Key, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary[f.Key]++;
            }
        }

        return dictionary.Where(s => s.Value == 1).Select(a => a.Key).ToList();

    }
}
```

And test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    [Test]
    public void Compare()
    {
        IDictionary<string, double> dictionaryOne = new Dictionary<string, double>()
        {
            {"he", 0},{"ey", 0 }
        };
        Dictionary<string, double> dictionaryTwo = new Dictionary<string, double>()
        {
            {"he", 0},{"ey", 0 },{"yg", 0 },{"gu", 0 },{"uy", 0 },{"ys", 0 }
        };
        var comparer = new DictionaryComparer();
        var list = comparer.CompareDictionaries(dictionaryOne, dictionaryTwo);
        Assert.That(4, Is.EqualTo(list.Count));
        Assert.That("yg", Is.EqualTo(list[0]));
        Assert.That("gu", Is.EqualTo(list[1]));
        Assert.That("uy", Is.EqualTo(list[2]));
        Assert.That("ys", Is.EqualTo(list[3]));
    }
}
```

Hope it make sense

Comment: Sorry forget to mention, the test is written in Nunit

Comment: But this is assuming I'm actually using hey and hey guys. I want to insert any text I want.

Comment: I think I will use your answer! I think with the foreach loop it might work.